# I cannot access 192.168.1.1

Tags: windows-7

This is my first post, so please be kind if the post is not placed in the right location. 
My home gateway / vivid wireless "4G" account is a few years old, but it seems that the speed is getting slow more often, which is quite frustrating. 
Looking on the forum, it is recommended to have a look at RSSI and CINR parameters, so I tried to logon to `192.168.I.I` as recommended, but got a fail -1 error when entering logon details. 
I followed The instructions of   [this website](http://www.192168ll.website/)

Can you please help? 
Thanks.

Comment: You say you got the error message when you tried to enter logon information.  That implies that you got to the right place but it didn't like your login credentials (which is typically just a password).  Can you confirm that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Its useful to understand what you're doing. What you really want is the address of whatever's being used as your default gateway I guess, which is *not* necessarily 192,168.1.1.

Use network and sharing center to take a look at the properties for the adaptor in question for the ipv4 default gateway. Alternately use the ipconfig command. Its always a set of 4 numbers between 1 and 255 each.